# A simple ReactJS example to show alert

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-dom

I am new to reactjs. I am using two text boxes one allows user to enter a number and display its square and another one to enter user first name and when click on submit button an alert box should come saying hello username.
I am able to produce the square but the alert is not working properly.

This is the HTML & CSS:

```js
class EssayForm extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
     value: '',
     fname:'',
  };

  this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange(event) {
    this.setState({value: event.target.value});
    this.setState({fname: event.target.fname});
  }

  handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    alert('Hello: ' + this.state.fname);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="example">
        <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
          <span>Square of:</span>
          <input type="text" value={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleChange} />
          <span>First name:</span>
          <input type="text" value={this.state.fname}  />
          <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
        </form>
        <div className="preview">
          <h1>Square of no is</h1>
          <div>{this.state.value * this.state.value}</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
} 

ReactDOM.render(<EssayForm />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

```css
.example {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  display: flex;
  padding: 20px;
  form {
    display: flex;
    align-items: flex-start;
    margin-right: 50px;
    * {
      margin-right: 10px;
    }
  }
  h1 {
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: bold;
  }
  .preview {
    white-space: pre;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Help me out in producing alert box with username entered.

Comment: You're overwriting `this.state.fname` with `event.target.fname`, which doesn't exist and is therefore undefined. Live code: https://codesandbox.io/s/shy-grass-hkvkz

Comment: why not just using the [example](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#controlled-components) provided in the official react page? It shows exactly what you are trying to achieve

Comment: @kboul It looks like that's exactly what OP used, tried to expand it and didn't exactly know how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing onChange handler on first name. Also it's advisable to use another onchange listener for first name as you do not want to update number value when you update the number. Here is a modified version of the code:

```
import React from 'react';

export class EssayForm extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            value: '',
            fname:'',
        };

        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
        this.handleNameChange = this.handleNameChange.bind(this);
        this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    }

    handleChange(event) {
        this.setState({value: event.target.value});
    }

    handleNameChange(event){
        this.setState({fname: event.target.value});

    }

    handleSubmit(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        alert('Hello: ' + this.state.fname);

    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="example">
                <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                    <span>Square of:</span>
                    <input type="text" value={this.state.value} onChange=
                        {this.handleChange} />
                    <span>First name:</span>
                    <input type="text" value={this.state.fname}  onChange=
                        {this.handleNameChange} />
                    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
                </form>
                <div className="preview">
                    <h1>Square of no is</h1>
                    <div>{this.state.value * this.state.value}</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think adding a separate handler method for each `<input>` is a good idea in general

Comment: Agreed @ChrisG, you can always pass in the on change function what input is calling {handleChange } and update the state accordingly

Answer (score 0):

There is no any change handler for `fname` state.

Please  [Refer This](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-zkf9wk?file=style.css)

Comment: Technically that's not true; OP's code has `this.setState({fname: event.target.fname});` which is indeed called. Anyway, an answer cannot just link elsewhere. It has to contain the fix in the text.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the following code to make it work.

```
class App extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            value: '',
            fname:'',
        };
    }

    handleChange(event, key) {
        let state = {};
        let value = event.target.value;
        state[key] = value;
        this.setState(state);
    }

    handleSubmit(event, name) {
        console.log(name);
        event.preventDefault();
        alert('Hello: ' + this.state.fname);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="example">
                <form onSubmit={(e) => this.handleSubmit(e)}>
                    <span>Square of:</span>
                    <input type="text"
                           value={this.state.value}
                           onChange={(e) => this.handleChange(e, "value")} />
                    <span>First name:</span>
                    <input type="text"
                           value={this.state.fname}
                           onChange={(e) => this.handleChange(e, "fname")}/>
                    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
                </form>
                <div className="preview">
                    <h1>Square of no is</h1>
                    <div>{this.state.value * this.state.value}</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Your `handleChange` is directly manipulating `this.state`, which you aren't supposed to do. `let state = this.state;` doesn't create a copy, not even a shallow one.

Comment: Thanks @ChrisG for telling the issue. I have updated the code with the fix.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create another handler for text change and to update the state of `fname` properly, and make sure you do not override `fname` when changing square input value.

Check the code below:

```js
class EssayForm extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
     value: '',
     fname:'',
  };

    this.handleSquareChange = this.handleSquareChange.bind(this);
    this.handleTextChange = this.handleTextChange.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  handleSquareChange(event) {
    this.setState({value: event.target.value});
  }

  handleTextChange(event) {
    this.setState({fname: event.target.value});
  }
 
  handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    alert('Hello: ' + this.state.fname);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="example">
        <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
          <span>Square of:</span>
          <input type="text" value={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleSquareChange} />
          <span>First name:</span>
          <input type="text" value={this.state.fname} onChange={this.handleTextChange} />
          <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
        </form>
        <div className="preview">
          <h1>Square of no is</h1>
          <div>{this.state.value * this.state.value}</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
} 

ReactDOM.render(<EssayForm />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

```css
.example {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  display: flex;
  padding: 20px;
  form {
    display: flex;
    align-items: flex-start;
    margin-right: 50px;
    * {
      margin-right: 10px;
    }
  }
  h1 {
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: bold;
  }
  .preview {
    white-space: pre;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: I don't think adding a separate handler method for each `<input>` is a good idea in general

Comment: @ChrisG you are right, it can be factorized, I just wanted to show him the solution to his problem, not to work on perf ;)  (but good point anyway)

Comment: Sure, but imo a question should always teach good practice if the opportunity arises, not just fix the immediate issue, otherwise it teaches bad practice by default, and we'll keep getting w3schools students.